# Updating from Rails 3.2.0 to 3.2.8 caused uninitialized constant Addressable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a project I was given a task to update all gems to stable. We were using rails 3.2.0 and some other gems. After updating to version 3.2.8 all tests crushed and I wa to fix them, the last error is `ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant Addressable`. I have a file with

```
module URIHelpers
  class << self
    ...
    def parse_url(url)
      Addressable.URI.heuristic_parse(url)
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

When calling URIHelpers.parse_url(url) I'm getting the above error. Where could be a error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got an answer by myself :) I was to add

```
require 'addressable/uri'
```

at the begging of the file. Before the update it was required somewhere in dependent gems and after it was out and i needed to add it to gemfile by myself and require it by hand.